# Where are Spring cacheable objects stored?

Tags: java, spring, jvm

I'am using Spring cache in my project and i want to analyse the java memory using visualVm, i would like to know where the cache objects

1. Are really stored in the heap?
2. Are there stored in the *eden* or in the *old* memory?

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm... They can be stored in either area... or niether at all, depending on the type of GC you use. This has nothing to do with Spring, it's up to the JVM to decide where to put an object and when to move it from one area to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to know where *any* object is stored, not just Spring objects. An object might be in eden, a survivor space, or tenured. In JDK 7 or earlier, certain things such as classes are stored in perm gen (per [this Oracle blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/about-g1-garbage-collector,-permanent-generation-and-metaspace): "*Permanent generation has been completely removed in JDK 8*".).

The garbage collector can and will move objects around under the covers. When and how that happens depends on the specific garbage collector you're using, which flags you're using to specifiy GC behavior, and what the rest of your application is doing with memory (reads and writes).

Eden, survivor, and tenured are all on heap. For older JVMs, some things will be allocated in perm gen which is off heap. Take a look at the "Monitoring Memory Consumption" in [this document on JConsole usage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) for more details.

Also from that doc, this is a nice summary of heap vs. non-heap:

> **Heap and Non-Heap Memory**
>
> The Java VM manages two kinds of memory: heap and non-heap memory, both of which are created when the Java VM starts.
>
> - Heap memory is the runtime data area from which the Java VM allocates memory for all class instances and arrays. The heap may be of a fixed or variable size. The garbage collector is an automatic memory management system that reclaims heap memory for objects.
> - Non-heap memory includes a method area shared among all threads and memory required for the internal processing or optimization for the Java VM. It stores per-class structures such as a runtime constant pool, field and method data, and the code for methods and constructors. The method area is logically part of the heap but, depending on the implementation, a Java VM may not garbage collect or compact it. Like the heap memory, the method area may be of a fixed or variable size. The memory for the method area does not need to be contiguous.